# Displaying chapter + section

Tags: header-footer, chapters

I want to display on every page header of my document the chapter/section/subsection number and name so that, for example, if we are scrolling down along the chapter 4, Utilities, it says

### 4. Utilities

on the header of that page. Then in another part we get for example, to section 3 of chapter 4, drawbacks

### 4.3 Drawbacks

In the second case, with the section, it works. But with the chapter it's displayed like this:

### Chapter Utilities

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[oneside, a4paper, titlepage, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}   
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{\chaptername\ #1}}
    \renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection\ #1}}
    \fancyhf{}
    \lhead{\fancyplain{}{CACS}}
    \rhead{\fancyplain{}{\rightmark }}

 \begin{document}
 \chapter{Utilities}
 % some text
 \clearpage

 \section{Drawbacks}
 % some text

 \end{document}
```

I'm new in Latex, I got this code (the renewcommands and the fancy package) form another post and modified it, but don't know exactly what I'm doing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I really wanted:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{\thechapter .\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection\ #1}}
```

In the code you posted it's true, there was no "chapter" word but the number was missing. Anyway, it helped me to realise which keyword was failing. As I said I'm new in Latex.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need \chaptername\ that=chapter

```
\documentclass[oneside, a4paper, titlepage, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
    \renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection\ #1}}
    \fancyhf{}
    \lhead{\fancyplain{}{CACS}}
    \rhead{\fancyplain{}{\rightmark}}

 \begin{document}
 \chapter{Utilities}
 \lipsum[1-30]
 \clearpage

 \section{Drawbacks}
 \lipsum[1-30]

 \end{document}
```